# Not able to navigate in mobile chrome browser

Tags: java, android, appium, selendroid, java-client

I have the following code which will start an application and will switch to mobile chrome browser and will navigate to www.google.com

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("BROWSER_NAME","Android");
capabilities.setCapability("device","Android");
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","hammerhead");
capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");
capabilities.setCapability("appPackage","com.android.calculator2");
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity","com.android.calculator2.Calculator"
              );
mobileDriver = new AndroidDriver(new URL(
                    "http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
mobileDriver.startActivity("com.android.browser","com.android.browser.BrowserActivity");
mobileDriver.get("www.google.com");
```

When .get method is called execution is throwing the below error:

> Not yet implemented. Please help us: http://appium.io

Answer (score 0):

If your needs are limited to *open the chrome browser to X url*, you should look at the ACTION_VIEW implicit Intent.

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Comment: After navigating if I need to input some data in search box also. In that case also I need to create Intent object?

Comment: which kind of data do you try to send in a search box ? If it is not sensitive informations, you could pass parameters by URL ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply by -

```
String urlString="http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub";
Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(urlString));
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setPackage("com.android.chrome");
try {
    context.startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    // Chrome browser presumably not installed so allow user to choose instead
    intent.setPackage(null);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```